# What is the meaning of a police car with no department or logo in the USA?

Tags: usa, officials

While traveling in the Southwest, I saw on two different occasions police cars that were painted all black, with no writing or logos on them. One was an older style of a police car, the other was a muscle car that looked brand new. They had all of the features of a police car, such as the lights near the windshield, bars for crashing at the front, antennae, but no markings anywhere, just black paint. The drivers also looked like the police.

Do these kinds of cars perform a special role? They seem useless as undercover vehicles.

Since they aren't marked, do I need to still follow their instructions, such as pulling over?

Comment: @Berend someone who is unfamiliar with these cars in the southwestern US is most likely to be a visitor.

Comment: Did you happen to notice specifically whether they had government license plates?

Comment: For me as tourist is relevant  and important to be sure that those who Identify as people with the aim to enforce the law,  actually ARE such, even if they don't look like... in east Europe is quite common to get robbed using similar tricks...

Comment: @Berend Seems like a case of programming in a boat : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ - in the US, Law Enforcement Officers have to identify themselves before attempting to detain you. They can, however, gather evidence to use against you in a court of law without identifying themselves. This is usually done by wearing a uniform or displaying a badge and/or ID. This is not as important as the fact that LEOs are almost always armed (even off duty). If someone with a firearm tells you to do something (and is close enough to use it), it really does not matter whether they are a police officer or not. Your options are limited.

Comment: and not every cop car is behind me to stop me and tell me it is a cop

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ - That is very true. Not every cop car, whether marked or unmarked, is going to stop you. In my area, cop cars have cameras that can read your license plate connected directly to onboard computers. The officer can get your registration and vehicle history way before deciding to pull you over. The cops in my area regularly drive under the speed limit to coerce other drivers to slow down. I, on the other hand, drive right by them without slowing down. As long as I am not breaking the speed limit or any other laws (expired registration, insurance, etc), they don’t pull me over.

Comment: @quora-feans Exactly what I was thinking; anything that exists at a certain location could be travel related for someone who is not from that location.

Comment: FYI: Regardless of whether or not local laws require you to pull over and stop for an unmarked vehicle, you're pretty much *always* required to yield the right of way to an unmarked vehicle (police or otherwise) when it's using its lights/siren.  Some positions (fire chief, etc) have portable light units on the dash of their personal vehicles so they can respond to emergencies after hours from home.

Comment: God bless you @DeanF.!! So many sheep will do whatever speed the cop's doing, no matter _how_ far under the limit he's going. I do the same thing you do (passing at the speed limit) and have _never_ had an issue with it!

Answer (score 53):

These are called [unmarked cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_car#Unmarked_car) - sort of a compromise between a marked car and a fully undercover vehicle.  The idea is that they're somewhat less easy to spot than a marked car, yet still have all the same equipment when it's needed.

They are very common, though the laws around their use may be evolving.

Yes, by law you do need to follow their instructions.  If you are uncertain whether it's a genuine police car or an impostor, you can call 911 to verify.

Comment: The law on unmarked cars can vary by state. In Georgia you have to pull over but may first proceed to a 'safe' location. [Ref](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2010/title-40/chapter-8/article-1/part-5/40-8-91)

Comment: @PhilippNagel That's what I said in my answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157701/5038

Comment: @Ryan somehow I missed it, I'll upvote, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Unmarked cars rarely have all the extra hardware on the outside, as it obviously identifies it as a police vehicle, defeating the point.

Comment: I've heard the thing about calling 911 to verify elsewhere before.  However there's a potential issue in the Southwestern US: Many places don't have cell phone signal, potentially for many miles.  (Same thing in the Western US in general, not just the Southwest.)  What's usually the rule or whatever in a situation like that?  Just put the hazard lights on and drive 20 miles to the next gas station?

Comment: @BillThePlatypus There are very wide range of "unmarked cars" from full, undercover cars to ones that have extremely light decals as to basically be a full police car unless you're looking in your side/rear mirrors, then the decals are very hard to spot and you think it is a "normal" car.

Comment: The other common word for these is "ghost cars".  They're almost exclusively used for traffic duty since they tend to blend in with the regular commuter cars - to answer OP's actual question of whether they're for any special duty.  People tend to stop speeding when they see police, and you can usually spot a marked car from far enough away that people react and adjust their driving before they can grab a radar reading.

Comment: " In Georgia you have to pull over but may first proceed to a 'safe' location."

The link provided is talking about *marked* cars not unmarked:-

(e) Whenever a motorist driving on the roadways of this state is directed to stop by a law enforcement officer in a law enforcement vehicle *marked as required* under this Code section, the motorist may continue to drive until a reasonably safe location for stopping is reached.

Answer (score 46):

I’m surprised nobody has mentioned what I believe to be the more common answer:

**Once a police department is finished with a car that has become too old, the department often removes its markings and auctions it off.**

If you don’t see *any* government markings anywhere (such as the license plate), I’d guess it’s no longer a police car (based on my experience in the southwestern USA), and the chances of the driver instructing you to do anything (i.e. impersonating a police officer) are very low.

But if someone in such a car *did* announce that they were a police officer, and they did not have an official uniform on with a badge, I'd call 911 and report them (since officers in an unmarked police car [must be in full uniform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1qnvv1nBoo), at least in certain states—I recommend researching the particular state you're in).

Retired 2006 Dodge Charger Police Car:
[image: Retired 2006 Dodge Charger Police Car]

You might also be interested in these articles:

[Thrillist](https://www.thrillist.com/cars/nation/how-to-buy-used-police-cars-tips-tricks-for-cop-auctions) says:

> [GovDeals](https://www.govdeals.com/) and [Public Surplus](http://www.publicsurplus.com/) are the kings of online auctions
>   and regularly liquidate cop cars for local municipalities. There are
>   thousands of cars to choose from, ranging from mint-condition cherry
>   rides that have barely been put through their paces, to those
>   unfortunate many that have been smashed to hell and have potentially
>   fatal amounts of bodily fluids staining the seats.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_vehicles_in_the_United_States_and_Canada#Skins/Paintjobs_and_Appearance:

> Currently, in the United States and Canada, the paint scheme for each
>   fleet is determined either by the individual agency or by uniform
>   state legislation as in Minnesota. Usually, state laws exist that
>   establish standards for police vehicle markings, and proscribe
>   civilian vehicles from using certain markings or paint schemes as is
>   the case in California.
>
> Today, most fleet markings on patrol vehicles are created from
>   reflective vinyl with an adhesive backing that is applied in a
>   peel-and-stick manner. Colors chosen to represent the departments
>   identity are typically chosen by the individual department, although,
>   as noted above, some states have specific guidelines for color schemes
>   and markings.

Comment: They don't generally sell cars with the light bars still attached, though!

Comment: True, though depending on state law, some types of light bars (at a minimum, not blue or red, and there may be other restrictions) may be legal. It may well not be illegal in many states to make your car look surprisingly like a police car as long as you don't cross a few red lines.

Comment: This is very common where I live (Germany). In fact, in the last two decades, police have actually deliberately changed the paint job of their vehicles to make them easier to resell. They [used to be a very distinctive beige-green paint job](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lautsprecherkraftwagen-Bayerische_Polizei.JPG#/media/Datei:Lautsprecherkraftwagen-Bayerische_Polizei.JPG), but [now they are stock silver, and the markings are actually put on with adhesive tape](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:VW_Passat_Polizei_Norderney.jpg#/media/Datei:VW_Passat_Polizei_Norderney.jpg).

Comment: So, what I take from this answer combined with the top-voted answer is that it's both very common for it to be police and very common for it to not be police. If that's true, that's... not super helpful.

Comment: Police cars do not need to have government license plates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The question did not say “light bars” and instead mentioned light near the windshield, such as the small circular white search light that police cars often have.  I see these remaining on former police cars frequently.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I don’t understand what you mean by “not super helpful”.  Wouldn’t one prefer to hear multiple answers if there are indeed multiple possible explanations? What wouldn’t have been helpful is if I had just upvoted an existing answer and pretended that it was sufficient.

Comment: @Ryan I don't really mean that the information provided in the answers is not helpful, but rather that the fact that they may or may not be police is not helpful. Although the question and "guess" in this answer does make it seem more speculative, which casts some doubt on it, especially combined with the other reference-supported answer which kind of says the opposite (even if both can technically be true). Also, a more helpful answer would probably be one that combines both of these facts, and addresses how you should respond to the vehicle as a result of that.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Updated with photo and links to articles.

Comment: @ZachLipton A friend of mine had a business selling equipment to police departments - mainly radios, "bull bars", etc. - and he had a Crown Vic painted all in black, plain bodywork, blackwall tires, spotlights, antennas, etc. It was his demo vehicle.

Comment: Why would police use an unmarked car and then wear full uniforms?  The point of using an unmarked car is usually for undercover work, so having a full uniform on would pretty well defeat the purpose.  Now I've heard that unmarked, plain-clothes officers are not allowed to, say, make a traffic stop if it isn't pertinent to their current assignment.  But having them clearly marked in any way would make undercover work basically impossible.  (Though I'm sure it varies by jurisdiction...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Having a uniformed LEO in an unmarked car has nothing to do with undercover work. Plain-clothes detectives operate out of uniform all of the time. Most of that is in a department vehicle. Undercover LEOs will drive cars that look nothing like police cars (usually seized vehicles). I had a LEO stepbrother who even shopped at Goodwill for his undercover clothes. Unmarked police cruisers & SUVs are all about blending into traffic to catch speeders or other random law breakers. The LEO has to remain in uniform to also perform normal patrol duties.

Comment: @Matt - Depending on the jurisdiction, police cars will display tax-exempt license plates. Federal, state, and local governments are not supposed to tax each other. It is difficult to distinguish a tax-exempt license plate from a generic license plate from a distance. An easier way to spot the difference is when the vehicle is from an area that uses color coded window and/or license plate stickers/decals to identify when the vehicle has been road inspected, registered, and taxed. The registration sticker observation is not fool-proof, though.

Comment: While I agree with most of this answer, I'm not sure on your comment in the first line - "the more common answer."  Is it more common to have a former police vehicle than an unmarked vehicle? Where I am from (which admittedly is _not_ the US) it was more common to see unmarked vehicles than former police vehicles, although it was still possible

Comment: @Midavalo - In Texas, government vehicles are frequently auctioned off. Though, the first right of refusal in the auction (unofficially) goes to other government agencies. For instance, there are a very large number of police vehicles that are now in use at airports as security patrol cars or courtesy crew cars for civilian pilots. Considering how roughly these cars are treated, those that do make their way into civilian hands are older and distinctively beat up. My local police department is about 50/50 marked to unmarked. But, they are all well kept and maintained in appearance.

Comment: @DeanF. I understand what happens, I'm just surprised that seeing one of these cars on the road might be _more common_ than seeing an unmarked police car.  I know it's possibly to see both, but didn't think that the old sold ones are more common than the current in-use unmarked police cars

Comment: In the days when the Ford Crown Victoria was the "standard issue" police car (they continued making it for nearly 20 years and selling it exclusively as a fleet vehicle), old cop cars were routinely purchased by taxi companies (though these were usually repainted) however many were purchased by individuals. I'd venture to get that there are 1000's of ex-police cars on the road in my state (in the Midwest) every day in private owner hands, so this is _very_ common. _Probably_ more common than an unmarked car in active-duty patrol use.

Comment: Also, in states with wonderful weather, such as southern California and other southwestern states, there are plenty more “old” cars on the road in general because they survive better there than locations with harsher conditions.

Comment: This is one of the strong plot lines (if any!) in [The Blues Brothers!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluesmobile).

Answer (score 12):

Police cars are frequently not painted with traditional police markings. They are typically used to blend into traffic or other roadside cars. That way, people who are speeding may be caught unaware as they speed past them. Cautious drivers may even slow down when seeing any car parked alongside the road. On some roads that are notorious for speeders, police departments may even park empty marked police cars to deter people from speeding. In any case, if you receive orders or directions from a uniformed police officer, or a police officer not in uniform who displays his badge or ID, you must obey them. Their mode of transportation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

There is another case that may occur and that is UTC (Uniform Traffic control). Sometimes it is needed for a police officer to be part of a traffic plan in a private run project (even if publicly funded such as repaving or traffic light replacement). The cases I have been involved with the general contractor will hire a traffic control contractor who will hire traffic control supervisors, flaggers (I did this summers in college) and UTCs. The UTCs are off duty police officers wearing full uniform (including badge and gun) but without access to the department's car, so the traffic control contractor owns (or leases) mostly equipped police cars (they don't have prisoner retention facilities or departmental radios) that are provided to the UTCs. Depending on local rules some UTCs may not issue tickets (jurisdictional issues), but they can call for backup and they can arrest you. You should follow their instructions (as well as flaggers and traffic control supervisors) as failure to do so is a ticketable offence (failure to obey a traffic control officer, similar to failure to obey a stop sign).

Publicly run projects use on duty police for their UTCs with departmental cars.

Answer (score 1):

Another situation not yet mentioned would be cars used in motion picture and television production.  I saw one on the road which I would guess was returning after a shoot, and had all of its insignia roughly scratched off and also had some moderately-small signs in the window saying "MOVIE PROP CAR".  The signs were large enough to be read, but small enough not to obstruct the driver's vision.  If a car is driving to a film or television shoot, I would expect that the crew might hold off on applying the insignia until they reach the location of the shoot, but if features like lights would need to stay on the car during stunt maneuvers, they would be securely attached at the shop before the shoot.